# Fluent Interfaces Implementation

Tags: c#, fluent-interface

In order to make my code more organized i have decided to use fluent interfaces; However by reading the available tutorials i have found many ways to implement such fluency, among them i found a topic who says that to create Fluent `Interface` we should make use of `Interfaces`, but he did not provided any good details in order to achieve it.

Here is how i implement Fluent API

#### Code

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public static Person CreateNew()
    {
        return new Person();
    }

    public Person WithName(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public Person WithAge(int age)
    {
        Age = age;
        return this;
    }
}
```

#### Using The Code

```
Person person = Person.CreateNew().WithName("John").WithAge(21);
```

However, how could i involve Interfaces to create Fluent API in a more effective way ?

Comment: What's not effective with this way?

Comment: @Sergey I was just wondering how to implement such Fluent API using Interfaces as that guys stated... Also i don't like using With***, instead i want to use Name, Age, etc... but i can't in this situation because of the property names

Comment: Any references to 'the guy'? And it would be nice to see bigger problem, because in this case you can simply do 'new Person { Name="John", Age=21 }'

Comment: http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2010/06/26/how-to-write-fluent-interface-with-c-and-lambda.aspx

Comment: he misses a lot of details in that topic that i can't even follow him

Comment: And in my project it will get more complicated than this i only created that preview for the sake of the question

Comment: I think in this blog he provides very complex solution for very simple problem, sorry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Implementing fluent API using `interface` is good if you want to control the sequence of the calls. Let's assume that in your example when name is set you also want to allow to set age. And lets assume on top of that you need to save this changes as well, but only after when the age is set. To achieve that you need to use interfaces and use them as return types. 
See the example :

```
public interface IName
{
    IAge WithName(string name);
}

public interface IAge
{
    IPersist WithAge(int age);
}

public interface IPersist
{
    void Save();
}

public class Person : IName, IAge, IPersist
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }

    private Person(){}

    public static IName Create()
    {
         return new Person();
    }
    public IAge WithName(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public IPersist WithAge(int age)
    {
        Age = age;
        return this;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        // save changes here
    }
}
```

But still follow this approach if it is good/needed for your specific case.

Comment: Thats it... neat and simple