# How to ensure the sequence of methods in fluent API?

Tags: c#, fluent, fluent-interface

I want to create fluent interface for some of my classes that I am building as part of a framework. I have created the methods and I am able to successfully chain methods. Now I want to ensure that I can handle the improper sequence of method calls.

The thing I am doing is something like CreateWorkflow -> OpenConfiguration -> ChangeUserName
In the above scenario it wouldn't make sense if ChangeUserName was called first because it is dependent on OpenConfiguration.

I am confused whether I am correct in creating a Fluent chain of methods for this scenario or not and how to make the sequence work. To me this scenario seems to be very suitable for creating a fluent API.

Comment: It seems that we can achieve what I want using interfaces as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800706/fluent-interfaces-implementation but this seems like an overkill for me. Is there any other better solution for this problem?

Comment: You're going to have to clarify what "better" means.  A few interfaces doesn't seem all that scary to work with.

Comment: If your goal is compile-time checking (which is a totally reasonable goal here), it seems to me that you're stuck either using different interfaces for the same core class or having each chained method return a different class entirely. The type system is what OO languages provide for enforcing these kinds of compile-time constraints.

Comment: @joshtkling Yes you are right, I am looking for a way for compile time checking, Ideally I want the user to have only valid options in intellisense.

Comment: @48klocs I am thinking of how many classes or interfaces I will end up with, I don't think they will be small in number if I take the route of using interfaces and classes. I was thinking maybe there are some best practices / approach for doing this?

Comment: @AfrazAli the approach you linked to is a your best bet if you want to go this route.  If the number of classes worries you, reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the sample code that enforces method chain in specific order.  I've used the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800706/fluent-interfaces-implementation/17801063#17801063) and fixed a minor issue in the original code. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/APhNkv) is the running code in dotnet fiddler

```
public interface IName
{
    IAge WithName(string name);
}

public interface IAge
{
    IPersist WithAge(int age);
}

public interface IPersist
{
    void Save();
}

public class Person : IName, IAge, IPersist
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }


    public IAge WithName(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public IPersist WithAge(int age)
    {
        Age = age;
        return this;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        // save changes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The real key is if you require a specific sequence for a fluent API to work you API needs improvement.  Maybe you should consider something a little different.  If ChangeUserName needs OpenConfiguration the consumer of the API shouldn't care.  Either internalize the dependency so the API becomes:

CreateWorkflow -> ChangeUserName

or if the consumer already has the Configuration Object you could use a Dependency Injection approach and make the API something like:

CreateWorkflow(IConfigurationManager) -> ChangeUserName

or

CreateWorkflow -> ChangeUserName(IConfigurationManager)

I show 2 approaches here as I am not sure what the scope of dependency is on your configuration class.  By either internalizing the need or adding a required parameter onto the signature of one of the methods you should be able to eliminate the fixed sequence issue.  Other than a clear "Start" and "Finish" to your API.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create Your Sequence In Your DatabaseContext

=> Enter The Code In OnModelCreating

```
builder
.HasSequence<int>("SequenceName", schema: "SequenceSchema")
.StartsAt(100)
.IncrementsBy(1)
.HasMax(int.MaxValue);

builder.Entity<TableName>()
.Property(a => a.PropertyName)
.HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR SequenceSchema.SequenceName");
```